# Replacing irregular number of slashes (/) using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a file with a number of slashes (`/`) and the number is not unique. The Part of data file looks like:

#### input.txt

```
30
///
10
40
23
44
//
////
31
/
54
/
```

Anybody please suggest me how to replace any number of slashes (`/`) with an undefined value (9999). I look for the output as

#### output.txt

```
30
9999
10
40
23
44
9999
9999
31
9999
54
9999
```

Comment: Note that ``/`` is a slash; ``\`` is a backslash. Which are you wanting to deal with?  Since the example consistently uses slashes, I've updated the question text to assume slash rather than backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either escape the `/` (a slash or solidus, be it noted; a backslash or reverse solidus looks like `\`) in the pattern, as noted by the other answers, or use a different character to mark the limits of the substitution:

```
sed 's@//*@9999@'
sed 's@/\{1,\}@9999@'
```

or other variations on the theme.  The use of `@` is arbitrary; any character that doesn't appear in the regex could be used trivially.

Comment: this would replace `foo/` with `foo9999` . I think op don't want this behaviour.

Comment: This replaces any non-zero number of slashes with 9999, which is the stated goal.  It can be trivially tightened up to only replace a line consisting solely of slashes instead.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^\/+$/9999/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Replace lines containing only 1 or more `/`s with `9999`. `/` needs to be escaped. `+` implies 1 or more.

With `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/^\/+$/,"9999")}1' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\/+$/9999/g'
```

Please find the execution [here](http://ideone.com/qLDgqv)

Answer (score 1):

You may use sed,

```
sed 's/^\/\+$/9999/' file
```

awk,

```
awk '/^\/+$/{$0="9999"}1' file
```

Comment: no need to say `$0 ~`, since it is the default. `awk '/^\/+$/{$0="9999"}1'` suffices.